# Getting exception even though im not supposed to with UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, action

Im creating a UIButton programatically:

```
UIButton *yesButton= [[UIButton alloc] init];
[yesButton addTarget:self
           action:@selector(buttonClicked:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[yesButton setTitle:@"ok" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
yesButton.frame = CGRectMake(width*0.09, height*0.82, width*0.1, height*0.05);
```

so I have this method called `buttonClicked`

```
-(void) buttonClicked:(id)sender {
     NSLog(@"%@",((UIButton *)sender).titleLabel);
}
```

so im pressing the button and here is the exception:

```
2013-07-20 23:13:10.989 Game[9593:c07] -[HudView buttonClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10592640
2013-07-20 23:13:16.565 Game[9593:c07] Uncaught exception: -[HudView buttonClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10592640
2013-07-20 23:13:16.567 Game[9593:c07] Stack trace: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0259f02e __exceptionPreprocess + 206
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01e50e7e objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0262a4bd -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 253
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0258ebbc ___forwarding___ + 588
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0258e94e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01e64705 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    6   UIKit                               0x002922c0 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
    7   UIKit                               0x00292258 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    8   UIKit                               0x00353021 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    9   UIKit                               0x0035357f -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 578
    10  UIKit                               0x003526e8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 546
    11  UIKit                               0x002c1cef -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 846
    12  UIKit                               0x002c1f02 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 273
    13  UIKit                               0x0029fd4a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 436
    14  UIKit                               0x00291698 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x02f5adf9 _PurpleEventCallback + 339
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x02f5aad0 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x02514bf5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x02514962 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x02545bb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2118
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x02544f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x02544e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x02f597e3 GSEventRunModal + 88
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x02f59668 GSEventRun + 104
    24  UIKit                               0x0028effc UIApplicationMain + 1211
    25  Game                                0x000028c4 main + 164
    26  Game                                0x000027d5 start + 53
)
```

any help?

EDIT:
this is my class which inherits from HudView class:

```
@implementation askDownloadHudView

-(id) initWithView:(UIView *)view {
    int height = (view.frame.size.height/4.8)*1.5;
    int width = (view.frame.size.width/1.142);
    self = [super initWithView:view animated:YES Height:height Width:width];
    self.text = @"Asking download";

    UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    textLabel.text= @"Do you want to download the level? download size is about 7mb";
    textLabel.numberOfLines = 0 ;
    [textLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.width.intValue,height*0.8)];
    textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    textLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    UIButton *yesButton= [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [yesButton addTarget:self
               action:@selector(buttonClicked:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [yesButton setTitle:@"ok" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    yesButton.frame = CGRectMake(width*0.09, height*0.82, width*0.1, height*0.05);

    UIButton *noButton= [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [noButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [noButton setTitle:@"no" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    noButton.frame = CGRectMake(width*0.8, height*0.82, width*0.15, height*0.05);

    [self addSubview:yesButton];
    [self addSubview:noButton];
    [self addSubview:textLabel];






    return self;
}

-(void) buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    //NSLog(@"%@",((UIButton *)sender).titleLabel);
}


@end
```

EDIT 2:implementation of HudView:

```
-(HudView *) initWithView:(UIView *)view animated:(BOOL)animated Height:(int)height Width:(int)width {
    self=[super init];

    self= [[HudView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(
                                                    roundf(view.bounds.size.width - width) / 2.0f,
                                                    roundf(view.bounds.size.height - height) / 2.0f,
                                                    width,
                                                    height)];

self.height=[NSNumber numberWithInt:height];
    self.width=[NSNumber numberWithInt:width];
    self.opaque = NO;
    [view addSubview:self];
    //view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    return self;


}
```

Comment: Try taking out the NSLog.

Comment: @AbdullahShafique didn't help

Comment: Is the object that creates the button and assigns it `self` as the target the same as the one that implements `buttonClicked:`?

Comment: @JoshCaswell check my update to the question

Comment: Apparently, the message is being sent to an instance of `HudView`, not `askDownloadHudView`. I think the problem might be in `[HudView initWithView:animated:Height:Width:]`. Can you post that method's implementation?

Comment: @AhmedMohammed i added the implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `-(HudView *) initWithView:(UIView *)view animated:(BOOL)animated Height:(int)height Width:(int)width`. You shouldn't allocate an instance of HudView. If you do that an instance of HudView will be returned instead of the subclass. You will have to change it to the following.

```
-(HudView *) initWithView:(UIView *)view animated:(BOOL)animated Height:(int)height Width:(int)width {
    self=[super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(roundf(view.bounds.size.width - width) / 2.0f,
                                         roundf(view.bounds.size.height - height) / 2.0f,
                                         width,
                                         height)];

self.height=[NSNumber numberWithInt:height];
    self.width=[NSNumber numberWithInt:width];
    self.opaque = NO;
    [view addSubview:self];
    //view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    return self;


}
```

Comment: thanks that worked! i didn't know i should allocate though, it sounds kinda strange but i guess i'll get used to it. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to change your code to use

```
UIButton *yesButton=  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

and add

```
[self.view addSubview:yesButton];
```

Then it worked.

You might be tapping another button?

Comment: I dont think the buttonWithType has anything to do with this. I checked it and indeed it didn't change anything. and yes i'm typing the correct button.

Comment: My answer responded to your original question, before "EDIT" where you added [self addSubview:yesButton];.  So in the original question, the button in question was never added to a view.  In UIButton Class Reference, buttonWithType is the only listing under "Creating Buttons" and the buttonType property is read-only.  In the app I created for my answer, if I create a button with [[UIButton alloc] init] it does not appear even if I use [view addSubview:yesButton].  I questioned if you were "tapping" (not typing) the correct button since in the code you provided, the button was not visible.